# Any issues converting ASP.NET applications from 1.1 Framework to 2.0?

Tags: asp.net

We are migrating many ASP.NET 1.1 web applications to new servers. We would like to convert *all* of them to 2.0 in the process. Ideally, in the end, the 1.1 framework will not even be installed on the new servers. We've never had major issues converting applications to 2.0 from 1.1. Our biggest issue has always been changing ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings to ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.

Has anyone else ever had major issues?

Are there any major things to look out for or consider up front?

Comment: It was a painful process for us.  I can't remember hardly any of the specific things that made it so difficult, but I do remember it sucked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a good resource on how to convert asp.net applications from 1.1 to 2.0 using visual studio 2005.

[Converting an ASP.NET Website from Version 1.1 to 2.0](http://www.pointercorp.com/Convert_ASPDOTNET_11_20.htm)

Edit:  Here is the MSDN step by step guide for converting apps:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479567.aspx

Answer (score 1):

When converting to 2.0 the only major issue I've run across was performance of compiled Regexes got much worse the way we were using it. Switching it to use the static Regex.Replace() method solved much of the problems.

I can't find the article that I found this in back then, but if I do I'll add it to this post.

The bottom line is make sure you test it not just for functional equivalence but for performance too.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem I've seen is that the new default is to use Web Site "projects". This should not be a problem if you're running Visual Studio 2005 SP1, where they corrected this problem.

I also had some odd problem that I think may have involved the vwd.webinfo file. Our web service application worked perfectly on my computer, but on the build server, it tried to become a web site "project", so it didn't compile. No compile == no symbols.